# Flex mobile: How to disable scale smoothing for sprite/bitmap

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, air, smoothing

In my Flex mobile project I need to draw a sprite with a couple of lines and rectangles and then rotate/scale it without edges smoothing. The problem is - when the sprite is drawn the first time, there is no smoothing, but once it get rotated/scaled, lines and rectangles edges become smoothed (or anti-aliased?). And they remain smoothed even when rotation is set back to 0 and scaleX scaleY are set back to 1.

I tried converting my sprite to bitmap like this:

```
stage.quality=StageQuality.LOW; // for performance reasons
.......
var tempSprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
// draw stuff on tempSprite

var b:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h, true, 0x0);
b.draw(tempSprite,null,null,null,null,false); // smoothing=false
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(b,"auto",false); // smoothing=false
bitmap.smoothing=false; 
myUIComponent.addChild(bitmap);
```

But it didn't help - still the bitmap becomes smoothed when it is rotated/scaled.

So, my question: is it possible to disable smoothing completely or at least return sprite to an unsmoothed state when rotation and scale values are reset?

Comment: Some screenshots of before and after may help me understand the issue here.

Comment: http://doptrix.com/images/user/image.PNG
Here is a part of screenshot. You should probably zoom to see the difference. But it's much more noticeable on iPhone/iPod.

Comment: I'm no designer; but I have to say I cannot tell the difference between the two images.  Perhaps someone with a sharper eye will be able to help you.

Comment: I updated the screenshot - zoomed to 300%. The difference is visible, especially on old devices with poor screen resolution. Upper sprite appears blurry.

Comment: Looks like the upper one has a very small grey border around it; but otherwise I still can't tell the difference.  Sorry; this one is beyond me.  Best of luck!

Comment: It looks to me like the positioning is off by a few subpixels.  Try to use the `pixelSnapping` property and see if that helps: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#pixelSnapping

Comment: No, I draw everything in integer pixels. I tried different values for pixelSnapping, pixelHinting and lots of other options without any luck. Initially my sprite is sharp until I rotate/scale it, then it immediately becomes blurry.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [Stage.quality](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#quality) - it states that smoothing has no effect when you set the quality to `StageQuality.LOW`. So at least you know it's not the smoothing :) Do the artifacts go away if you raise the quality?

Comment: What kind of rotation is that? "rotation" or 3D?

Comment: I don't know what kind of "smoothing" this is. It only appears when I transform sprite, so my guess is that it's "scale smoothing".
I do rotation, rotationX, rotationY and scaleX, scaleY in my game. As far as I noticed, touching any of these parameters cause smoothing of the sprite.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AIR for mobile and enabling GPU mode then your bitmaps will always be smoothed.  All you can really do is hide the smoothing by not scaling/rotating your bitmaps and making sure that none of the containers in the draw list hierarchy are either.  I had a similar problem to yours and my only fix would've meant rewriting my display scaling code so I just lived with the blurriness until my next project.